# 10th Anniversary of Aviation SE!

Tags: discussion

In December 2023 aviation.stackexchange.com turns 10 years old. Congratulations on asking, answering, voting, and building this community for a whole decade!

Whenever a Stack Exchange site turns 10 we like to celebrate by encouraging users to reflect on their experiences here.

How did you first discover the site? Do you have a favorite question or answer that helped you solve a problem? Any funny anecdotes or other insights on your time here, that you would like to share? We want to hear it all!

Answer (score 9):

I started [following](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/94110/farhan) this site when it was in [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42572/aviation). A few months later when the site launched, I was in the first few users to sign up.

There are a lot of questions which I like. I have contributed many questions and answers, and my knowledge increased from the awesome folks we had and still have here.

Overall, I am very happy about this forum and the community.

Comment: Congratulations on turning 10. Thank you, JamieC, RalphJ, and DeltaLima for all that you do as moderators on Aviation. Congrats to your entire community.

Answer (score 8):

Only on this site could one find people both well-informed and lighthearted enough to collaboratively figure out how many [sneezing gophers](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/80712/31425) it takes to launch a 747.